# Is there anyway that I can find all files indent with n-space?

Tags: indentation

I have files indent with 2, 3, and 4 spaces. They all have multiple indentation levels. Is there any existing tool allow me to find all the files indent by n spaces?

Moreover, Is there anyway that allow me to convert all the indentation in all the files to a uniformed n-spaces indentation in batch?

Comment: Should a file match if *any* line in the file is indented by "N" spaces?  What's your goal with the conversion: changing all 2, 3, or 4-space indents to (some N) spaces, or to tabs? Or from tabs to spaces?

Comment: @jeffSchaller If leading space of every line is M*N in that file (M=0,1,...) and the minimum none zero M == 1, then we say this is indented by N.

Comment: The final goal is to unify the indentation to a given X-spaces.

Comment: You may use `.editorconfig` file which has `indent_size` value.